# How to export multiple radgrids to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, telerik, radgrid

I have a web application that fills several RadGrids with data. 
I want to export them all into one excel file with multiple sheets.

I found a [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/exporting/excel-export-multiple-grids/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid) on telerik's site that does exactly what I wish to do.

However, I get a build error saying that `GridTableView` does not contain a definition of `GenerateXlsxOutput`.

I've been looking around but I can't really find any good information about it.

Here's a [printscreen](http://prntscr.com/o429jq) of the error I get.

The libraries I'm using

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.OpenXml.Xlsx;
using xi = Telerik.Web.UI.ExportInfrastructure;
using Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.Model;
using System.IO;
```

Comment: What version of telerik are you using? (Deleted my answer since it was not correct)

Comment: I'm not enterery sure the Telerik.Web.UI.dll file says it's version 2018.3.910.45

Comment: odd... your library should have the `GenerateXlsxOutput()` method then and shouldn't complain about it.

Comment: I made a new fresh webproject and I get the same error there

Comment: If you can, try updating your ASP.NET AJAX `.dll` files from Telerik